# How to write an SQL query to get max number of counts for the most number of travelling of a user within a month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been given a task by my manager to write a SQL query to select the max number of counts (no of records) for a user who has travelled the most within a month provided that if the user travels multiple places on the same date, then it should be counted as one. For instance, if you look at the following table design; according to this scenario, my query must return me a count of 2. Although traveller_id "1" has traveled three times within a month, but he traveled to Thailand and USA on the same date, that is why its count is reduced to 2.

[image]
[image]

I have also developed my logic for this query but I am unable to write it due to lack of syntax knowledge. I split up this query into 3 parts:

1. Select All records from the table within a month using the MONTH function of SQL
2. Select All distinct DateTime records from the above result so that the same DateTime gets eliminated.
3. Select max number of counts for the traveller who visited most places.

Please help me in completing my query. You can also use a different approach from mine.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `count` aggregation in a cte then `select top(1)`:

```
with u as
(select traveller_id,
count(distinct visit_date) as n
from travellers_log
where visit_date between '2022-03-01' and '2022-03-31'
group by traveller_id)
select top(1) traveller_id, name, n from u inner join table_travellers
on u.traveller_id = table_travellers.id
order by n desc;
```

Comment: Actually, we only need to return counts from the same month. One of the records from above example is from different month

Comment: The answer of my count must be 2 and not 3

Comment: @AbdulAhad check my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. One thing I would like to ask. If there a way not to hardcode date string after between clause. I mean there can be any dynamic date

Comment: @AbdulAhad it can be replaced with a subquery.